# Booting error in Yocto project for STM32MP157a custom board

Tags: stm32, yocto

I am learning yocto project and I got a developemnt board which is based on stm32mp157a chip. This board is not the developemt board from the ST. It is a custom development board from local vendor. I started with the basic yocto project and compiled core-image-full-cmdline.

I choose my machine as stm32mp1, which I changed in local.conf. I also uploaded the image to sd card, according to the instructions from [here](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_populate_the_SD_card_with_dd_command). I think partition of the sd-card is ok. But when I try to see the terminal via minicom, the program is stuck at some places.

The messages are below:

```
�NOTICE:  CPU: STM32MP157AAC Rev.B
  NOTICE:  Model: STMicroelectronics STM32MP157A-DK1 Discovery Board
  INFO:    PMIC version = 0x21            
  INFO:    Reset reason (0x15):           
  INFO:      Power-on Reset (rst_por)     
  INFO:    FCONF: Reading TB_FW firmware configuration file from: 0x2ffe2000
  INFO:    FCONF: Reading firmware configuration information for: stm32mp_io
  INFO:    Using SDMMC                    
  INFO:      Instance 1                   
  INFO:    Boot used partition fsbl1      
  NOTICE:  BL2: v2.6-stm32mp1-r2.0(debug):v2.6-dirty(a1f02f4f)
  NOTICE:  BL2: Built : 13:14:26, Nov 23 2021
  INFO:    BL2: Doing platform setup
  INFO:    RAM: DDR3-DDR3L 16bits 533000kHz
  INFO:    Memory size = 0x20000000 (512 MB)
  INFO:    BL2: Loading image id 1
  INFO:    Loading image id=1 at address 0x2ffff000
  INFO:    Image id=1 loaded: 0x2ffff000 - 0x2ffff226
  INFO:    FCONF: Reading FW_CONFIG firmware configuration file from: 0x2ffff000
  INFO:    FCONF: Reading firmware configuration information for: dyn_cfg
  INFO:    FCONF: Reading firmware configuration information for: stm32mp1_firewall
  INFO:    BL2: Loading image id 4
  INFO:    Loading image id=4 at address 0x2ffc5000
  INFO:    Image id=4 loaded: 0x2ffc5000 - 0x2ffd9820
  INFO:    BL2: Skip loading image id 8
  INFO:    BL2: Skip loading image id 9
  INFO:    BL2: Loading image id 2
  INFO:    Loading image id=2 at address 0xc0500000
  INFO:    Image id=2 loaded: 0xc0500000 - 0xc051cdf8
  INFO:    BL2: Loading image id 16
  INFO:    Loading image id=16 at address 0x2ffc0000
  INFO:    Image id=16 loaded: 0x2ffc0000 - 0x2ffc44d2
  INFO:    BL2: Loading image id 5
  INFO:    Loading image id=5 at address 0xc0100000
  INFO:    Image id=5 loaded: 0xc0100000 - 0xc01ece88
  NOTICE:  BL2: Booting BL32
  INFO:    Entry point address = 0x2ffc5000
  INFO:    SPSR = 0x1d3
  NOTICE:  SP_MIN: v2.6-stm32mp1-r2.0(debug):v2.6-dirty(a1f02f4f)
  NOTICE:  SP_MIN: Built : 13:14:26, Nov 23 2021
  INFO:    ARM GICv2 driver initialized
  INFO:    Set calibration timer to 60 sec
  INFO:    stm32mp1 IWDG1 is secure
  INFO:    ETZPC: CRYP1 (9) could be non secure
  INFO:    SP_MIN: Initializing runtime services
  INFO:    SP_MIN: Preparing exit to normal world


  U-Boot 2021.10-stm32mp-r2 (Oct 04 2021 - 15:09:26 +0000)

  CPU: STM32MP157AAC Rev.B
  Model: STMicroelectronics STM32MP157A-DK1 Discovery Board
  Board: stm32mp1 in trusted mode (st,stm32mp157a-dk1)
  DRAM:  512 MiB
  Clocks:
  - MPU : 650 MHz
  - MCU : 208.878 MHz
  - AXI : 266.500 MHz
  - PER : 24 MHz
  - DDR : 533 MHz
  WDT:   Started with servicing (32s timeout)
  NAND:  0 MiB
  MMC:   STM32 SD/MMC: 0
  Loading Environment from MMC... *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

  In:    serial
  Out:   serial
  Err:   serial
  Previous ADC measurements was not the one expected, retry in 20ms
  **************************************************** 
  * ERROR USB TYPE-C connection in unattached mode   *
  * Check that USB TYPE-C cable is correctly plugged *
  *     Current too low, use a 3A power supply!      *
  ****************************************************
```

Where is the error, or what I am missing? Do I need to create my own BSP to make this work, as mine is not the stm32mp1 discovery board.

Comment: That last error seems to be quite straight-to-the-point... Are you sure that your power supply is correct/suitable? If so, you will have to make some changes. U-boot is checking some ADC values to determine the power supply current, however it does assume that the device tree matches the hardware (i.e. there is a relevant ADC, and that ADC has the properties described in the device tree)

Comment: I tried with the exact power supply, with 4 A cuurent supply, but still the same error.

Comment: Are you powering it through USB-C?

Comment: nope, because that custom board does not have the usb c.  Here is the link for the custom board 

https://www.emtrion.de/de/products/emsbc-argon-single-board-computer.html

Comment: I see. Generally you can get through this check by creating a patch for u-boot with commenting [this line](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/f95232c6f06cc0747801bb6a4372b33825ab0164/board/st/stm32mp1/stm32mp1.c#L735) (u-boot is specifically looking for current on the USB power delivery ADC, which you are not using). However if there are other noticeable changes compared to the discovery board, this error is only the first one, and chances are that you will have to do more grunt work before the kernel finally boots.

Comment: On a bit brighter note, it seems that there are some BSP available for your board specifically, created by the vendor

Comment: @skandigraun thanks a lot for metioning that. Their BSP is in dunfell version, I am building in kirkstone version. Can you tell the process to import the package from dunfell to kirkstone, so that I don't have anz error?

Comment: It requires generally 3 steps. 1. Look for `layer.conf` files in the layer, and add `kirkstone` to the `LAYERSERIES_COMPAT` variable (the variable should be already present, having `dunfell` in it. Just add `kirkstone` separated by a space). 2. Run `$YOUR_PATH/poky/scripts/contrib/convert-overrides.py $PATH_TO_NEW_BSP_LAYER` script to update the recipes to the new syntax. (You might want to check the changed files, the script is not exactly a genius). 3. Try to build, and hope for the best.